# alphabet navigation with paging in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, paging

I need to do alphabet navigation with paging for my grid/table in asp.net mvc(C#) application.

I am looking for something similar to [jquery ListNav](http://www.ihwy.com/Labs/Demos/Current/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx)

The above plugin is good in doing alphabet navigation, but when a particular alphabet contains more than hundred records/rows, i need to implement paging with it. So the user wont have to scroll all over the page and it looks compact in the screen.

Any suggestions or plugins for this functionality?

Comment: still no better solution. I am trying to replace/ remove that plugin from my application.

Comment: Five years later.... Did you find it yet?

Comment: We have made that on our own by adding the alphabets and the click actions to the corresponding alphabets.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit here. It's not clear to me that the update reflected the authors intent. If someone could confirm/deny this maybe we can roll it forward?